# Bootstrap 3 and collapsing menu

Tags: menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I create a simple expandable menu (with bootstrap 3). It works properly but I can't make just one voice open at the time. The icon never shows up and I can open the menu but if another element is open it doesn't close.

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="nav-header"> 
  <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MenuEurope">Europe <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-angle-down"></i></a>            
  <ul style="list-style: none;" class="collapse" id="MenuEurope">
   <li><a href="/austria">Austria</a></li>  
  </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="nav-header">
 <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MenuNorth-America">North America <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-angle-down"></i></a>                       
  <ul style="list-style: none;" class="collapse" id="MenuNorth-America">
     <li><a href="/canada">Canada</a></li>
     <li><a href="/united-states">United States</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

This is the js code that I'm using is:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {     

    $('[data-toggle=collapse]').click(function(){   
        // toggle icon
        $(this).find("i").toggleClass("icon-angle-right icon-angle-down");  
    });

    $('.collapse').on('show', function (e) {  
        // hide open menus
        $('.collapse').each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('in')) {
            $(this).collapse('toggle');
        }
        });

    })

 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons are not showing up because you have incorrect classes. There is no "angle" icons, I'm guessing you meant arrow? In addition the JS toggling the classes does not match correctly as well.

You have an issue with your HTML tags, specifically Line #6 in your above example is incorrect and should not be there. Otherwise the accordions seems to work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I meant arrow. The line #6 is just a mistake due to editing code here in stackoverflow. The accordions work fine but I can't have just one "menu voice" open at the time. You mention a problem with js and the classes. Can you please explain me where is the problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: When you toggle the class via jQuery, you use "icon-" when it should match your HTML, such as "glyphicon-".

Comment: You are right. Now the only problem that I can't solve is the fact that I have all the submenu open. You said the accordions work fine. Do you have just one voice open at the time?

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to when you say "voice", but I have your answer: if you want to only let one open at a time, you need to wrap all of them in a parent element. Then each accordion should have a "data-parent" property with the selector for the parent. See the docs/example:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: Thanks a lot wrap all the elements was the solution.